# Imagick:UnableToLoadModule

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagick

I have install the ImageMagic extension

this is my php version
[php version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIGTz.png)

this is my imagick version
[imagick version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HRuj.png)

this is my example php code :

```
?php 
   try{
    $im = new Imagick()
    $im->readImage('C:\xampp\htdocs\ldpc\application\views\gambar1.jpg');
    if ($im->getImageHeight() > 500) {
     $im->resizeImage(500, 500, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
    }
    $im->sepiaToneImage(90.5);
    header('Content-type: ' . $im->getFormat());
    echo $im->getImageBlob();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

and it show like this :

> UnableToLoadModule `C:\img\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPEG_.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1277

how can I fix It ?
please help me sir, i'm kinda new on php programming.

Comment: Ensure you have the dynamic DLL library installed, and define `MAGICK_HOME` environment variable in Apache's virtual host.

Comment: can you give me a link where i can download that dynamic library ?

Comment: http://imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: Did you pass throught this problem?