# imagemagick error - unable to load module

Tags: php, apache, imagick

I have set up imageMagick on my windows machine with `WAMP`. I'm trying to convert a `pdf` to `jpg` and via the command prompt everything works fine. If I run the php script, I get the following error.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to load module `C:\imagemagick\IM_MOD_RL_PDF_.dll' in D:\wamp\www\docms\aaaapdf\sample.php on line 2

( ! ) ImagickException: unable to load module `C:\imagemagick\IM_MOD_RL_PDF_.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1277 in D:\wamp\www\docms\aaaapdf\sample.php on line 2
```

I think this might have something to do with environment variables. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check this: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/installing-and-using-imagemagick-with-imagick-php-extension-php_imagick-dll-on-wamp

Comment: Thanks but imagmagick already loads in phpinfo. I still get the same error

Comment: At phpinfo you can see the row: "ImageMagick supported formats", pdf is probably not supported over there.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078829/imagickunabletoloadmodule

Comment: Another useful link: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,125599,125615

Comment: Everything was set but it didnt work so I just ran the command  with exec() through php and got the result I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I would also recommend switching to a Linux environment because the installation for Imagick is easier.